# Windows Azure Role Environment - Unable to find assembly

Tags: azure, dotnetopenauth, azure-role-environment

I'm getting this error when I call Windows Azure Role Environment.
I've checked and DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common.dll as Copy Local = True.

Any idea?

> System.TypeInitializationException was caught   HResult=-2146233036
>   Message=The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
>   Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime   TypeName=
>   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(String
>   localResourceName)
>          at Platform.Services.Api.Common.FileStorage.GetFilePath(String
>   azureLocalResourceNameFromServiceDefinition, String blobContainer,
>   String fileName) in d:\TFS
>   Project\DEV\Platform\Platform.Development\Platform.Services.Api\Common\FileStorage.cs:line
>   16
>          at Platform.Services.Api.Controllers.ReportingController.PrintProcessInteraction(Int64
>   id) in d:\TFS
>   Project\DEV\Platform\Platform.Development\Platform.Services.Api\Controllers\ReportingController.cs:line
>   217   InnerException: .ModuleLoadException
>          HResult=-2146233088
>          Message=The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain.
>
> ```
>    Source=msshrtmi
>    StackTrace:
>         at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String
> ```
>
> errorMessage, Exception innerException)
>               at .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )
>               at .cctor()
>          InnerException: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>               HResult=-2146233076
>               Message=Unable to find assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'.
>               Source=mscorlib
>               StackTrace:
>                 Server stack trace: 
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.Run()
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>                    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream
>   stm)
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[]
>   reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm,
>   SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[]
>   args)
>                 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>                    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>                    at System.AppDomain.get_Id()
>                    at .DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function,
>   Void* cookie)
>                    at .DefaultDomain.Initialize()
>                    at .LanguageSupport.InitializeDefaultAppDomain(LanguageSupport*
>   )
>                    at .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )
>                    at .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )
>               InnerException:

Comment: What does this have to do with DotNetOpenAuth? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Runtime is doing something with DotNetOpenAuth (I don't know why... this seems really strange). To solve this, I've created a Startup Task that installs DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common.dll into GAC ([following this solution](http://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure/)).

```
type .\GACUtils\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common.dll
type .\GACUtils\gacutil 
.\GACUtils\gacutil /nologo /i .\GACUtils\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common.dll 

exit /b 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you compile to x64 or Any CPU?

Comment: "Any CPU"... I've changed it to x64 but without success.